# S3 deleting files in Glacier storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Our S3 bucket contains a mix of objects in Standard and Glacier storage class(due to the lifecycle rules we setup). I want to understand how to delete the Glacier storage class objects. I looked at the Glacier console and we don't have a Vault/archive to delete. So, my guess is that S3 is managing the Glacier vault for us. I also looked at the lifecycle rule blog post(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/) to validate this.

TL;DR

So, is deleting an object (in Glacier storage class) from S3 (using the aws CLI or lifecycle rules) sufficient to delete it from Glacier as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is deleting an object (in Glacier storage class) from S3 (using the aws CLI or lifecycle rules) sufficient to delete it from Glacier as well?

Yes, it is.  Deleting the object from S3 removes it from Glacier.

> The `GLACIER` storage class uses the very low-cost Amazon Glacier storage service, but you still manage objects in this storage class through Amazon S3.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html

When S3 stores objects in the `GLACIER` storage class, S3 doesn't put that data into *your* Glacier in *your* AWS account.  S3 seems to have its own, separate interface to Glacier.  (Similarly, EBS snapshots are stored "in S3," but not in *"your"* S3.)

Comment: Yes, that's what i guessed. Thanks for confirming the same.

Comment: If you use a normal FTP client (instead of AWS Console) to delete files from your S3 bucket ... will those individual files still be deleted from Glacier?  You don't have* to delete from AWS CLI or AWS console for AWS to know to delete that file from Glacier right?

Comment: @Rees yes, deleting the object from S3 by any means would be sufficient, but I'd suggest using the console or CLI to verify that the expected action occurred.  If your bucket has object versioning enabled, of course, then you need to ensure that the object version is actually removed, since deleting an object in a versioned bucket only hides the object from ListObjects (but not ListObjectVersions).

Comment: thanks so much @Michael-sqlbot !, i'm mainly using Glacier for a backup of an external hard drive so think I'll have versioning off and simply periodically sync my external with an S3 bucket/Glacier via FTP client.  Thanks for the quick reply!